# RPM SPEC: Restart external service only if config file was changed after package update

Tags: rpm-spec

I have a RPM package which add config to `/etc/rsyslog.d/`. I don't want to restart rsyslog's service after each update because apparently rsyslog [can't do graceful restart](https://serverfault.com/q/1053728). So, I would like to restart rsyslog service only if config file changed after package update.

Is there a way to configure that in rpm-spec file?

Comment: I haven't done this with RPMs but it looks like https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Scriptlets/ could be a good resource for building a package with your own scriptlet that tests the config file(s) and follows your criteria for deciding when/if to restart syslog.